# Fitting cos^n using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have to fit some data to the function f(x) = f(0)*cos^n*x

Below are a few of the lines of code I've written but it gives me a recursion depth limit exceeded error and I don't know how to fix it. Where have I gone wrong?

```
f(x) = f(0)*(cos^n)*x
fit f(x) 'NameOfDataFile' using 1:2 via n
```

Comment: Do you mean `f(0)` or `f0`? Do you mean `cos(x)**n`? `f(x)=f(0)*cos(x)**n` would be a recursive function, `f(x) = f0*cos(x)**n` not. But then you have to assign a value to `f0`, e.g. `f0=1.234`.

Comment: I mean f at x=0. I noticed I have incorrectly understood the function. What it should mean is f at x=0 * (cos(x))^n. How would I properly write this in gnuplot code?

Comment: Then this would be `f(x)=f(0)*cos(x)**n`.  Power() or  `^` in gnuplot is `**`. However, if you mean `f(0)` then it is a recursive function and gnuplot has a certain recursion depth limit. I wouldn't even know how to plot, e.g. the function `f(x) = f(0)*cos(x)**2`, because of recursion. Can you show the data you want to fit it to?

Comment: f 0, 10, 20, 30

Comment: x 2668, 2652, 2470, 2006

Comment: I'm still puzzled. So, `f(2668)=0` and `f(2652)=10` and `f(2470)=20` and `f(2006)=30`? Can you give a bit more background? Why the recursive function `f(x)=f(0)*cos(x)**n`? Why not `f(x)=a*cos(b*x+c)**n+d` or something like this?

Comment: It is the angle our measurement set up is set at and the corresponding number of counts. The data we have gathered should be fit to the function for f(x) I have mentioned before. We have to find a value for n which should be at around 2.

Comment: I see I have swapped around f and x in my comments so f(0)=2668. It still gives me an odd fit with a value for n of 0.5.